# Using tabIndex for td

Tags: yui, rich-text-editor, html-table, tabindex

Inserted editable table performed using simple combination of `table`, `tr` and `td` tags.

Is it possible to make its cells switchable by clicking `tab` button, using `td` `tabIndex` property (or anything else)?

For now, clicking `tab` button inside any cell (`td`) inserts 4 spaces inside it, obviously. Of course, I may listen to `keydown` or `keypress` events and then make something like `preventDefault()` and then play with `$('#nextTdId').focus()`.

It is only thoughts without any practise. It may be that someone had this problem too.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using pure HTML under Firefox 14. Pressing TAB key will move focus to next tab index, instead of inserting 2 spaces. Could you add your HTML in your original post?

Comment: Could you share your implementation with me, Jay?

Comment: Here in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UYVJd/). Note that `CONTENTEDITABLE` attribute isn't applicable for `TD` element.

Comment: I'm trying to perform new functionality to [this](http://www.garbageburrito.com//blog/entry/1070621/table-editor-for-yuis-rich-text-editor) plug-in.

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, sorry. You might want to check if it has some kind of editor settings during its initialization.

Comment: I've found no special setting for that.